# Adding TimeSpan only to Time of Date and not Date

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have 2 DateTime's:

```
DateTime beginDate = 2000/01/01 14:00

DateTime endDate =  2000/01/01 14:30
```

I calculate a timespan between these 2 hours:

```
TimeSpan span = endDate.Subtract(beginDate);
var myValue = beginDate.AddMinutes( span.Minutes ).TimeOfDay.Ticks

//Trying to get this equal to the endDate by using the beginDate + myValue
//I have to use myvalue, because this value comes from the DB and this piece 
//of code sits in another class than the above code
DateTime otherDate = beginDate.Date.Add( new TimeSpan( myValue ) )
```

The Problem is I keep on getting 0:30 back and I should get back 14:30.
I understand why, its because beginDate.Date gives you 2000/01/01 00:00, but I cant use beginDate.TimeOfDay.Add because it is a readonly field.
How do I achieve that it only add the myValue to the time of the given date??

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do and why you're jumping through so many hoops.

Comment: By using the beginDate and myValue to calculate and get the same result as the endDate

Comment: Unclear what `myValue` is meant to represent. By all logic if `beginDate` + `myValue` should be equal to `endDate` then `myValue` should be equal to `span`. Why all the `.TimeOfDay`, `.Date`, `.Minutes`, `.Ticks` confusion? If you're just trying to serialize a `TimeSpan` for saving in a database, use the `.Ticks` property and no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx).

`span.Minutes` only gives you the minutes part. So of `1:30` it won't be 90. It'll be `30`. Use `TotalMinutes` to get the `90`.

Also `beginDate.Date` should be changed to `beginDate` because by using `Date` you are removing the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime otherDate = beginDate + span;
```

Comment: I have to use myValue and beginDate to calculate. I've updated my post. Its because I save myValue and beginDate in the DB, at a later stage and in another class I retrieve these 2 fields out of the DB and then must use them to result back to the endDate